# How can i get piped string from server and parse it in xcode?

Tags: ios

I have data on a server and I am trying getting this data as a piped string. I wrote the sever-side code but I don't know how can I retrieve this data and parse it in iOS. Here is an example of my [data](http://www.tefaltv.com/ios/iOshandler.ashx?act=10). Is there any article or code that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few starting points: For retrieving a stream of data from a server, have a look at Apple's [Stream Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000188i). To parse your data, you can use a `NSScanner` ([String Programming Guide: Scanners](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000147-BCIEFGHC)) or a `CFXMLParser` ([XML Programming Topics for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFXML/CFXML.html)) if you have valid XML data.

Answer (score 0):

Your output doesn't seem to be in a valid format like xml or json. But if your glat with the content as a string inside your app use this code snippet

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURLRequest *site_request = 
        [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://...."]
                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                     timeoutInterval:10.0];

    NSURLConnection *site_connection = 
        [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:site_request
                                        delegate:self];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)site_connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    NSString *site_response = 
        [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"OUTPUT: %@", site_response);
}
```

The log will put out the string inside the console.